# `No such file or directory` while copying from local filesystem to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, windows-10, hdfs, hadoop2

I have installed local single node Hadoop on Windows 10 and it appatently works.

Unfortunately, when I am trying to copy files to Hadoop from local filesystem, it swears:

```
λ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ../my_models/*.model hdfs://localhost/tmp
copyFromLocal: `../my_models/aaa.model': No such file or directory
copyFromLocal: `../my_models/bbb.model': No such file or directory
copyFromLocal: `../my_models/ccc.model': No such file or directory
copyFromLocal: `../my_models/ddd.model': No such file or directory
```

As you see, it lists all model files in local directory, which proves it sees them. Unfortunately, it doesn't copy them.

Simultaneously I can create directories

```
λ hadoop fs -mkdir -p hdfs://localhost/tmp/

λ hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost/
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - dims supergroup          0 2018-04-22 22:16 hdfs://localhost/tmp
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: I don't think it accepts a glob pattern. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#copyFromLocal

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting this error because :

1. You **can't use an asterisk(*)** to specify the file format with the files you want to copy. You can only mention the path to the file or dir.(In your case this is the possible cause)
2. The folder you're copying from LFS is in the root dir. or some other dir. which HDFS user can't access.

Try using `cd` command as HDFS user to the same folder where your files exist, if the **`permission denied`** error persist then you must copy the files to `/tmp` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a for loop for this something like below
for file in aaa.model bbb.model ccc.model; do hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ../my_models/$file hdfs://localhost/tmp; done